# Remove background image at certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have my background image change every time the page loads. That function works fine, but I also want to have the background image set to none when screen width is less than 640px for the mobile users. I tried using the screen.width and screen.availWidth, but both did nothing. My background image stays no matter what the screen size is.

```
function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
    var myImages = ["images/bg_images/audi_tt.jpg", "images/bg_images/watercooled.jpg", "images/bg_images/aircooled.jpg"];
    var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
    var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
    var windowWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
    if (windowWidth <= 640) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
    } else if (windowWidth > 640) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
    }
}
window.onload=changeImg;
```

Comment: Since you tagged JQuery, have you tried `var windowWidth = $( window ).width();`?

Comment: That works! Is there a way to change it so it will automatically get rid of it when you resize the window and not only when you refresh the page?

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured out the resize. Thanks for the help, Jon!

Comment: Glad it worked! Not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it all using jQuery this way:

```
function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
    var myImages = ["images/bg_images/audi_tt.jpg", "images/bg_images/watercooled.jpg", "images/bg_images/aircooled.jpg"];
    var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth <= 640) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'none');
    } else if (windowWidth > 640) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')');
    }
}
$(window).load(changeImg());
```